# Why doesn't the CheckerFramework let me override an `Object` parameter with an `Object` parameter?

Tags: java, checker-framework

The `OverrideBug` class has a single method, which uses a static constant:

```java
import java.awt.Component;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import javax.swing.DefaultListCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.JList;

public class OverrideBug extends DefaultListCellRenderer {

  private static final NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();

  @Override
  public Component getListCellRendererComponent(
      JList<?> list,
      Object value, // <-- Line 13, error here
      int index,
      boolean isSelected,
      boolean cellHasFocus
  ) {
    if (value instanceof Double) {
      value = format.format((Double) value);
    }
    return super.getListCellRendererComponent(
        list, value, index, isSelected, cellHasFocus
    );
  }
}
```

When I compile this, the checker framework gives me an error on line 13:

> [override.param] Incompatible parameter type for value.

The method I'm overriding has this signature:

```
public Component getListCellRendererComponent(
    JList<?> list,
    Object value,
    int index,
    boolean isSelected,
    boolean cellHasFocus
)
```

As you can see, this perfectly matches the overriding method. The Checker Framework is objecting to overriding an Object parameter with an Object parameter!

Why am I getting this error? It makes no sense at all. And what can I do about it besides a `@SuppressWarnings` annotation? I prefer to fix warnings rather than suppressing them, if possible. I especially don't like to suppress warnings that I don't understand, because I've learned through experience that this is a risky practice.

For a reproducible test case, see https://github.com/SwingGuy1024/CheckerQuestions

(When I first posted, the link didn't work, but it should work now.)

Comment: Which java and checker framework version do you use?

Comment: BTW: The link is broken. Get a 404

Comment: I'm using version 3.39.0.
I just noticed that the repository is marked private. I haven't figured out how to make it public yet. Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: The repository is now public.

Comment: maybe the error message gives more information than posted here: e.g. `found   : @Initialized @NonNull Object` `required: @Initialized @Nullable Object` - but I do not know that framework, neither do I use Maven (standard plain Java compiler does compile that code without warnings)